# Please give me an example for differences of cidr and inet datatypes in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

From the [DOC](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-net-types.html#DATATYPE-INET-VS-CIDR)

> The essential difference between inet and cidr data types is that inet accepts values with nonzero bits to the right of the netmask, whereas cidr does not.

Please give me example for differences of cidr and inet datatypes in PostgreSQL.

I do not understand that completely and want to see differences visually.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems I have found [the answer](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CABRT9RAr2bFrxdx93H_aEQsKmuchMwurSfENP8itSpExsWsF7g%40mail.gmail.com)

Say, if you have a /8 netmask, the `cidr` type requires that all the
24 rightmost bits are zero. `inet` does not have this requirement.

```
db=# select '255.0.0.0/8'::cidr;
255.0.0.0/8

db=# select '255.1.0.0/8'::cidr;
ERROR:  invalid cidr value: "255.1.0.0/8"
DETAIL:  Value has bits set to right of mask.
```

And inet allows this:

```
db=# select '255.1.0.0/8'::inet;
255.1.0.0/8
```

Comment: @klin: that is precisely the quote that Eugen already has in his question